# Link directly to a tab in adminhtml tab widget

Tags: adminhtml, javascript, url

Is it possible to link directly to a tab on a backend page, using URL fragments?

In particular, I want to link to the "Manage Label / Options" tab on the "Edit Product Attribute Page":

[image: Screenshot]

I hope for something like `/admin/catalog_product_attribute/edit/attribute_id/1/#product_attribute_tabs_labels` where the URL fragment `#product_attribute_tabs_labels` is read in JavaScript and the tab gets selected.

If that's not possible out of the box, how could this feature be added with an additional script and without rewriting templates?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually it's possible with a URL parameter `?active_tab=$id`.

## How to find the right tab id

Find the responsible tab container class. This is a child class of `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tabs`, in my case, `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Attribute_Edit_Tabs`.

You'll find calls to `$this->addTab()`, usually in the methods `_beforeToHtml()`, or `_construct()`. The first parameter of `addTab()` is the tab id:

```
$this->addTab('labels', array(
    'label'     => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Manage Label / Options'),
    'title'     => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Manage Label / Options'),
    'content'   => $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/catalog_product_attribute_edit_tab_options')->toHtml(),
));
```

So, the URL is `/admin/catalog_product_attribute/edit/attribute_id/123/?active_tab=labels`, generated with this code (within an adminhtml block):

```
$this->getUrl('adminhtml/catalog_product_attribute/edit',
    array('attribute_id' => 123, '_query' => array('active_tab' => 'labels'));
```

---

## How it works

Let's have a look at the responsible code:

### Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tabs::_beforeToHtml()

Sets the active tab based on URL parameter or session value. If `setActiveTab()` is not called, the `_activeTab` property defaults to the first added tab:

```
    if ($activeTab = $this->getRequest()->getParam('active_tab')) {
        $this->setActiveTab($activeTab);
    } elseif ($activeTabId = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->getActiveTabId()) {
        $this->_setActiveTab($activeTabId);
    }
```

### app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/widget/tabs.phtml

Here, the result of `getActiveTabId()` is passed to the varienTabs instantiation in JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    <?php echo $this->getJsObjectName() ?> = new varienTabs(
        '<?php echo $this->getId() ?>',
        '<?php echo $this->getDestElementId() ?>',
        '<?php echo $this->getActiveTabId() ?>',
        <?php echo $this->getAllShadowTabs()?>);
</script>
```

The `varienTabs` constructor takes the active tab id as parameter and shows it. For the curious, the code is in `js/mage/adminhtml/tabs.js`

Answer (score 3):

To further fschmengler's detailed response.

To link directly to a product tab, find the active_tab in class `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tabs`

```
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tabs.php
```

My requirement was to directly link to the upsells tab on the product edit page from a custom grid (see actions -> url -> params).

```
    $this->addColumn('action', array(
        'header'        =>  Mage::helper('reports')->__('Action'),
        'type'          => 'action',
        'getter'        => 'getId',
        'actions'       => array(
            array(
                'caption'   => Mage::helper('reports')->__('Edit Product'),
                'url'       => array(
                    'base'      => 'adminhtml/catalog_product/edit',
                    'params'    => array('active_tab' => 'upsell')
                ),
                'target'    => '_blank',
                'field'     => 'id'
            )
        )
    ));
```

The other 'labeled' tabs include: inventory, categories, related, crosssell, reviews, tags,  customers_tags, customer_options (custom?), configurable.

The tabs above 'inventory', such as 'Images' or 'Design' require you to know the attribute set group id e.g. group_20 (see `eav/entity_attribute_group_collection`).